# Working with 16bit offsets and segments in Radare2

Tags: radare2, dos

I have a simple DOS COM program which I want to analyse using Radare2:

```
  USE16
  ORG 100h

  mov ax, cs
  dec ax
  mov ds, ax

  mov dx, message+10h
  mov ah, 9
  int 21h
  ret

message:   db "Hello there!$"
```

(Use `yasm` or `echo "jMhIjti6HQG0Cc0hw0hlbGxvIHRoZXJlISQ=" | base64 -d > test.com` to compile it to a binary.)

When I load the binary using `r2 -b16 test.com` radare shows that I'm at `0000:0000`.

How can I tell radare that the actual program address should be `0000:0100`?

Also how can I tell radare that the offset loaded into the `dx` register points to `message`? In other words, can I tell radare that `dx` is an offset using a segment that starts at `0000:0100 - 0x10`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `-m 0x100` to load the binary at a specific address, as can be seen in `r2 -h` output:

> -m [addr]    map file at given address (loadaddr)

So you can do something like this:

```
$ r2 -m 0x100 -b 16 test.com

[0000:0100]> aa
[x] Analyze all flags starting with sym. and entry0 (aa)
[0000:0100]> pdf
╭ (fcn) fcn.00000100 13
│   fcn.00000100 ();
│           0000:0100      8cc8           mov ax, cs
│           0000:0102      48             dec ax
│           0000:0103      8ed8           mov ds, ax
│           0000:0105      ba1d01         mov dx, 0x11d                ; 285
│           0000:0108      b409           mov ah, 9
│           0000:010a      cd21           int 0x21                     ; '!'
╰           0000:010c      c3             ret
```

Regarding your second question, the bytes that interpreted as `mov dx, 0x11d` are `ba1d01`. As you can see, 0x01d1 is hard coded so r2 won't add `message +` to it.

You can create a flag using `f str.message 13 @ 0x10d` but it would probably not  be helpful in your case.

Comment: Thanks. I tried `-m` before but it felt a bit hacky. I thought there is a way of manually defining sections/segments where I could specify what is the base address of the section and then instruct `r2` to use that section after `0000:0103`.

Comment: Interestingly, when I do `r2 -m 0x110 -b 16 test.com`, then `f str.message 13 @ 0x11d` and then `aa`, the message will be displayed in the comment and the disassembly becomes `mov dx, str.message`. Not a solution since code offsets are wrong but it feels so close. :)

Comment: Thanks, I accepted the answer since I think you covered everything and nobody seems to know better. Looks like `radare2` in its current version is not the right tool to disassemble old 16-bit DOS executables.